# How to create hierarchical json structure by slice string path

Tags: json, go

I'm building a backend for a file manager written in Go.

I'm looking for a way to make an example slice string path.

```
sliceStr := []string{
   "/file_A.txt",
   "/folder_B/file_B.txt",
   "/folder_C/sub_folder_C/file_C.txt",
   "/folder_C/sub_folder_C/file_C_2.txt",
}
```

to create an api that returns a hierarchical json structure to pass to the frontend using [Devextreme FileManager](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/FileManager/BindingToHierarchicalStructure/Vue/Light/). Like below

```
[
    {
        "name": "file_A.txt",
        "isDirectory": false
    },
    {
        "name": "folder_B",
        "isDirectory": true,
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "file_B.txt",
                "isDirectory": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "folder_C",
        "isDirectory": true,
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "sub_folder_C",
                "isDirectory": true,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "name": "file_C.txt",
                        "isDirectory": false,
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "file_C_2.txt",
                        "isDirectory": false
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: I wrote a small module that does essentially this. But it is using a dot as separator and not a slash. https://github.com/bluebrown/labelparser. You could modify it to your liking. Maybe it helps to get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can  try this method

- join  the  slice  into  a  byte array
- Implement you own json UnmarshalJSON

```
type  Yourstruct  struct {
    .......
}
func (t *Yourstruct ) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error
```

[demo case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618940/how-can-i-implement-unmarshaljson-for-a-type-derived-from-a-scalar-in-go)